# NodeJS forever does not work on startup

Tags: linux, node.js, archlinux, reboot, forever

I'm working on a Rest Service working with NodeJS(iojs) on an old Raspberry Pi 1 running on Arch Linux. Everything works fine but its not starting on Reboot.

What I tried:
Crontab without user:

```
crontab -e
@reboot /usr/local/iojs/bin/forever start /x/y/server.js
```

and with user:

```
crontab -u x -e
@reboot /usr/bin/sudo -u x -H /usr/local/iojs/bin/forever start /x/y/server.js
```

Both versions work manually executed.
I also tried to do it with systemctrl:

```
/etc/systemd/system/rest_api.service
[Unit]
Description=Rest Api

[Service]
ExecStart=/x/y/rest_api/start_service.sh
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

This should execute start_service.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
forever start /usr/local/rest_api/server.js
exit
```

Starting it throws an error

```
systemctl start rest_api
Error getting authority: Error initializing authority: Error calling StartServiceByName for org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1: Timeout was reached (g-io-error-quark, 24)
Failed to start rest_api.service: Connection timed out
```

I'm a beginner in some of those topics, therefore I'm struggling to find the mistake. Actually I think this should be simple.

Thank you,
Matthias

Comment: FYI, there's http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/ for Raspberry Pi specific issues.  It doesn't seem to be particularly active, but perhaps worth a try.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a raspberry specific issue. However, I searched for related issues but my search was unsuccessful.

Answer (score 2):

If some people are still interested, this works perfectly:

1) `npm install forever -g && npm install forever-service -g`

2) rename your js script to **app.js**, go to its location with **cd** and type:

```
forever-service install myService
```

3) add the following line in **/etc/rc.local** :

```
sudo service myService start
```

I hope it will help!

Comment: if you do not want to rename your script file, then use `--script <script-file-name>` parameter in `forever-service install myService` command

Answer (score 0):

I was having this same problem. Got it working with the way you have it in scenario #1 above.

```
sudo crontab -e
#added this to the bottom
@reboot /usr/bin/sudo -u pi -H /usr/local/bin/forever start /home/pi/server.js
```

I thought it didn't work at first, but after rebooting the pi I gave it a solid 5 minutes before running:

```
forever list
```

And it showed up:

```
info:    Forever processes running
data:        uid  command             script                                       forever pid  id logfile                    uptime
data:    [0] L8AA /usr/local/bin/node /home/pi/server.js 3086    3108    /home/pi/.forever/L8AA.log 0:0:12:21.877
```